# Can't get my mail.app filter I created to work on messages that are coming in to the Gmail IMAP spam folder

Tags: mac, gmail, imap, apple-mail, spam-prevention

On Leopard, I use Mail.app. I have filters set up. They work. Except for this new one I made. It works when I choose Apply Filters manually. But does not seem to filter incoming messages.

It is my only filter that operates on something in the IMAP Gmail Spam folder. I think that mail just sees this as any other IMAP folder, so I don't know why it won't work. But do you think that Mail.App does realize that this IMAP/spam folder is actually a spam/junk folder and for some reason because of this it prevents my filter from being run?

As I said all my other filters work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the spam detection of gmail is a filter applied before others...

How to deal with it:

- To filter mails flagged as spam: add `label:spam`  in the `"Has the words"` input box.
- To avoid the spam flagging, create a filter that describes the cases when Gmail should not flag the incoming messages as spam and then check `"Never send it to spam"`.

source: [googlesystem.blogspot.com](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/bypass-gmails-spam-filter.html)

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have multiple gmail account so would prefer to filter once they are in mail.app. But if that is not possible I will do it your way and the same filters to all my gmail accounts.

Basically I like to check my spam folder before deleting messages, but right now i am getting so many "ED Meds" and "ED Pills" messsages that they even flood my spam folder... so I wanted to make filters to clear those out... and leave the rest of my spam for manual checking before deleting

Comment: you could export/import your filters in the gmail webapp...